# In Which folder in my springboot project should i initialize git?

Tags: java, git

I have created a new SpringBoot project with the *Spring initializr*. I want to add git to the project to track it. In which folder would it be appropriate to initialize git?

I want to do it in the `src` folder but I fear it might not track all the files needed.

Comment: The root of the project

Answer (score 1):

**Init git at the root level of your project.**

Your fear is justified, since many spring projects have many additional files that should be tracked in addition to your source code and resource files (documentation, `pom.xml`, etc)